# insert page break in the report viewer visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I want to create page break in report viewer  VS  C#2010  I creat report from

select name ,surname.....  ,country

when country change can it insert page break

Remark  feild country i show on header but not show in table

it work good it show coun try on the header every page but how can I make it separate sheet between peo ple in each country

```
David    England
Robert   England

---------Page break
Lee      China

---------Page break
musachi   Japan
niko      Japan
```

I try to use group when I group many record disappear

Answer (score 0):

Adding a group onto the country should have resolved this, group by the country and tick the add page break after, you say records disappear what records?